# Can quark-gluon plasma ever be close to an ideal gas of asymptotically free quarks?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, ads-cft, quarks

The question inspired by an upcoming  [colloquim at UCB](http://physics.berkeley.edu/index.php?option=com_dept_management&act=events&Itemid=444&task=view&id=1235).

A naive interpretation of quark asymptotic freedom seems to imply that at high enough energies they should be weakly interacting. On the other hand, the quark-gluon plasma accessible experimentally via heavy ion collisions is claimed to be close to an ideal liquid. There is also a lot of excitement about this because of AdS/CFT correspondence (see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2026/1739) and related questions at Physics.SE).

Shouldn't the quark-gluon matter phase diagram be close to an ideal gas at least in some
 low-density & high-temperature region?
In other words, is quasi-independent quark gas picture of QCD ever valid? And is there a simple reason why?

Comment: I'm not an expert on QGP, but you need high energy *and* short distance scales (lest confinement come to bite you) for asymptotic freedom, so high temperature and high density...